# problem when running Amelia package - non existing variable

Tags: r, missing-data, multi-level

I would like to run Amelia function in Amelia package in a small dataset in order to handle some missing values. Here is the code :

```
am_hier <- amelia(karas_hier, ts = "type_questionnaire", 
cs = "id_unique", 
noms = "cat_prof_max",  
ords = c("q19_karasek_n", "q20_karasek_n", "q21_karasek_n", "q22_karasek_n"), 
polytime = 2, 
intercs = TRUE, 
p2s = 2)
```

But I have this error:

```
Amelia Error Code:  38 
 The following variable(s) are characters: 
     2
You may have wanted to set this as a ID variable to remove it
from the imputation model or as an ordinal or nominal
variable to be imputed.  Please set it as either and
try again
```

The problem is that I don't have a variable named "2". I don't know how to fix this error.

1. What this error means? 2) How to correct this error?

Thank you a lot!

## Update

Here is a reproducible example

```
structure(list(id_unique = c("A70_136_B_F", "A70_136_B_F", "A70_136_B_F", 
"A70_136_B_F", "A70_137_M_N", "A70_137_M_N", "A70_137_M_N", "A70_137_M_N", 
"A70_138_D_S", "A70_138_D_S", "A70_138_D_S", "A70_138_D_S", "A70_216_R_M", 
"A70_216_R_M", "A70_216_R_M", "A70_216_R_M", "A70_217_K_B", "A70_217_K_B", 
"A70_217_K_B", "A70_217_K_B", "A70_218_L_A", "A70_218_L_A", "A70_218_L_A", 
"A70_284_S_H", "A70_284_S_H", "A70_284_S_H", "A70_317_J_A", "A70_317_J_A", 
"A70_317_J_A", "A70_317_J_A", "A70_318_R_P", "A70_318_R_P", "A70_318_R_P", 
"A70_318_R_P", "A70_319_D_N", "A70_319_D_N", "A70_319_D_N", "A70_319_D_N", 
"A70_321_P_J", "A70_321_P_J", "A70_321_P_J", "A70_321_P_J", "A70_322_K_M", 
"A70_322_K_M", "A70_322_K_M", "A70_322_K_M", "A70_323_M_S", "A70_323_M_S", 
"A70_323_M_S", "A70_323_M_S"), type_questionnaire = c("t0", "t1", 
"t2", "t3", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", 
"t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", "t2", "t3", "t0", 
"t1", "t2", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", 
"t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", 
"t0", "t1", "t2", "t3"), cat_prof_max = c("Infirmier", "Infirmier", 
"Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", 
"Infirmier", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", 
"Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", 
"Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", 
"Aide-soignant", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", 
"Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", 
"Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", "Aide-soignant", 
"Aide-soignant", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", 
"Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", 
"Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", "Infirmier", 
"Infirmier", "Infirmier"), q19_karasek_n = c("D'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord"), q20_karasek_n = c("D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord"), q21_karasek_n = c("D'accord", "D'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"Pas du tout d'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"D'accord", "Pas d'accord"), q22_karasek_n = c("D'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"D'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", 
NA, "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", "Pas du tout d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "Tout à fait d'accord", "D'accord", 
"D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", "D'accord", 
NA, "D'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Tout à fait d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "D'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", "Pas d'accord", 
"Pas d'accord")), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Post part of the data that you're using (with the `dput` function). If `karas_hier` is a dataset, maybe it's the second column its referring to.

Comment: I added a reproducible example in the updates. Thank you !

Comment: `ts` needs a numeric variable indicating time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I convert `ts` into  numeric but now I have another error message. `amelia starting
Error in unique(na.omit(x[, i]))%%1 : 
  argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire`